# JWT Token Remove or logout

Tags: c#, jwt

I'm doing user-controlled using JWT token.
No problem logging in, but how to log out?

Comparison of the database
my opinion,
do you have better method suggestions

Token controller
I validate the user in UyelikOnaylama class

```
    public class TokenController : ApiController
{  
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(TokenRequestDto dto)
    {
        UyelikOnaylama uyelikOnaylama = new UyelikOnaylama();
        var sonuc = await uyelikOnaylama.AsekronMethod(dto);
        Random random = new Random();
        if (sonuc==1)
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, dto.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, random.ToString()+"asd"),
                new Claim("scope",  random.ToString()+"tasd"),
                new Claim("scope",  "**")
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "localhost",
                audience: "localhost",
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(30),

                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("!^'+sda1905SDASDQdqqdD'^+!34123")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Hatalı kullanıcı adı ya da parola");
        }

    }

}
```

I'm checking with a startup class

```
    public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string secretKey = "!^'+sda1905SDASDQdqqdD'^+!34123";
        var opt = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        var prov = new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider[1];
        prov[0] = new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider("localhost", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
        opt.IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = prov;
        opt.AllowedAudiences = new String[1] { "localhost" };
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(opt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but you get an AccessToken from your JWT Service? With this Token you get the desired rights for accessing data on the WebApi (or whatever you do with it). If your User logs out, the AccessToken is still available.

If this is your problem, simply remove the token from the List holding all of them. Also you can reduce the time, when the Token expires

## Solution

Add this 3 classes into your project

```
public static class JwtSecurityKey
{
    public static SymmetricSecurityKey Create(string secret)
    {
        return new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret));
    }
}

public sealed class JwtToken
{
    private JwtSecurityToken Token;

    internal JwtToken(JwtSecurityToken token)
    {
        this.Token = token;
    }

    public DateTime ValidTo => Token.ValidTo;
    public string Value => new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(this.Token);
}

public class JwtTokenBuilder
{
    private SecurityKey SecurityKey = null;
    private string Subject = "";
    private string Issuer = "";
    private string Audience = "";
    private Dictionary<string, string> Claims = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private int ExpiryInMinutes = 5;

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddSecurityKey(SecurityKey securityKey)
    {
        this.SecurityKey = securityKey;
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddSubject(string subject)
    {
        this.Subject = subject;
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddIssuer(string issuer)
    {
        this.Issuer = issuer;
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddAudience(string audience)
    {
        this.Audience = audience;
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddClaim(string type, string value)
    {
        this.Claims.Add(type, value);
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddClaims(Dictionary<string, string> claims)
    {
        this.Claims.Union(claims);
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddExpiry(int expiryInMinutes)
    {
        this.ExpiryInMinutes = expiryInMinutes;
        return this;
    }

    public JwtToken Build()
    {
        EnsureArguments();

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
          new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, this.Subject),
          new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        }
        .Union(this.Claims.Select(item => new Claim(item.Key, item.Value)));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                          issuer: this.Issuer,
                          audience: this.Audience,
                          claims: claims,
                          expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(ExpiryInMinutes),

                          signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                                                    this.SecurityKey,
                                                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

        return new JwtToken(token);
    }

    #region Privates
    private void EnsureArguments()
    {
        if (this.SecurityKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Security Key");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Subject))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Subject");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Issuer))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Issuer");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Audience))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Audience");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And in your Startup class, call this method:

```
    private void ConfigureTokenServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Token Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters =
                         new TokenValidationParameters
                         {
                             ValidateIssuer = true,
                             ValidateAudience = true,
                             ValidateLifetime = true,
                             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                             ValidIssuer = "Custom.Security.Bearer",
                             ValidAudience = "Custom.Security.Bearer",
                             IssuerSigningKey = JwtSecurityKey.Create("Yout securitykey which must be a very long string to work")
                         };

                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("OnTokenValidated: " + context.SecurityToken);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };

                });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Guest",
                policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Add here your roles"));
        });
    }
```

And add this line

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

to

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

With this you can then filter inside your Controller, which is the sense of JWT:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("YourRoute")]
[Authorize("Role")]
public class MyController 
{
```

or you can do this directly on a method.

```
    [Authorize("Role")]
    [HttpGet, Route("YourRoute")]
    public IActionResult HttpGet()
    {
```

Tell me if I understood your issue correct and if there are any problems implementing this

Comment: Yes I use JWT token
where it the list
how reduce the time

Comment: its hard to tell you a solution if there is no code to see. Can you edit your question and provide the code of the JWT Service?

Comment: You should not handle the Tokens inside a Controller, let me create a fast example

Comment: These classes apply to netcore

IServiceCollection

Comment: But this not invalidate the token, write?